# Looking for the category of IC that would send a signal to all selected output pins simultaneously?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, integrated-circuit, device

What would a multiplexer like device that allowed multiple outputs to be addressed simultaneously be called? - am looking to address multiple outputs in an array (many as possible - probably ganged) and then send a control signal (digital and or analogue) that appears on all selected pins at same time.

Comment: what should be on the outputs before the output enable signal is activated?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could work around either floating or ground as long as it's known - three state output would be best though (hi,low,float).

Comment: Have discovered serial to parallel shift registers since originally posing the question - still keen to know if there are any other categories including analogue solutions.

Comment: use a 3-state latch on the output ... https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT373.pdf   ... or even better https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT595_Q100.pdf ... or a bidirectional switch https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74gtl2003.pdf

Comment: If they are simply ganged all of the time, then a fanout buffer might be suitable. If only some need to be driven, and the others high Z, then three-state buffers like 74240 migth be suitable. If all need to be programmable then your ser/par shift register might be the best

Comment: A cross-point switch sounds like what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is what a crossbar switch does: it's a many-to-many matrix with addressable connections between inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement this is with many SPST analog switches whose data inputs are all connected to your digital/analog signal.
With, e.g., 74xx4066 logic devices, you get four outputs per chip, but you can easily combine multiple ones.